# Linear gradients not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I read that the syntax had updated to remove the prefix, but I tried all of the following and none of them are working:

```
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#82dc7b), to(#61a45c));
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
        -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
        -ms-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
        -o-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
        linear-gradient(to bottom, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
```

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients

Comment: Oh, i thought you meant had updated *recently*.  That's been the standard for a while now...and what it means is that all that `-whatever-linear-gradient` crap should go away and be replaced with just the standard `linear-gradient`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
background: #82dc7b; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #82dc7b 0%, #61a45c 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#82dc7b), color-stop(100%,#61a45c)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #82dc7b 0%,#61a45c 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #82dc7b 0%,#61a45c 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #82dc7b 0%,#61a45c 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #82dc7b 0%,#61a45c 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#82dc7b', endColorstr='#61a45c',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Check out the following resource for help: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Strange... I have a lot of luck with the colorzilla tool.  Did you try generating your gradient code using that tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#82dc7b), to(#61a45c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82dc7b, #61a45c);
```

Also, check out http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/